# Cocos vs AndEngine for android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, andengine, cocos2d-android

I want to make a game using Tiled Map Editor and I want to move the character around using a D-Pad  for moving the character

So I'm wondering which Engine would be better
AndEngine or Cocos2d

Keep in mind i'm a beginner at this so I'd like to stare at a lot of tutorials. :-D

Thanks

Comment: For beginners I would always recommend to pick the engine for which you can find more tutorials (or even books).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both engines supprot loading TMX map quite easy and input from D-PAD. So if your requirements are only that, there is no big difference. Just use what you familiar with.

Comment: thanks :-) Decided on Cocos. Any tutorials out there. I found some specific to sprites but none for Tiles. Just snippets

Answer (score 4):

Cocos2d-android don´t have support anymore. You must use cocos2d-x, cross-plataform, use JNI to use c++ code. More info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711047/1077364).

Cocos2d-x is great to create games, but i have not use AndEngine never.

Answer (score 4):

```
Libgdx      : Java (Good documentation/Sample example)
                   (Android/iOs/3D support also)

Cocos2d-x   : C++  (Good documentation and Sample example)
                   (Android/iOS/window/bada/blackbarry/etc/3D supports)

AndEngine   : Java (Documentation is **OK** but bit of issue )
                   (Android)

Cocos2d-android : Java (bIT of documentation/ easy to use )
                       (Almost dead only android)
```

If familiar with **java** `choose LibGdx` **OR**   `cocos2d-x` for **C++**.

I recommended that you should choose **cocos2d-X**

Comment: Completely right , I use AndEngine is great lib with many extensions that do every thing , but poor in documentation , I use also Libgdx very nice lib with great documentation

Answer (score 3):

I started with Cocos2d-android as it appeared a better option , but after a while I was shocked that I could not find any tutorials for Cocos2d-android

either go the Cocos2d-x-android , or take AndEngine
I never tried Cocos2d-x-android , but I can confirm that AndEngine is pretty good and got lots of examples and enough tutorials to get you started [AndEngine lacks documentation though .. but that won't be a problem if you started with the official examples]

Edit: AndEngine is kinda dead now

Answer (score 2):

There are a hell lot of bugs in AndEngine...
i had first the same dilemma of choosing one thing over other but my options include libgdx,andengine and cocos2dx...

Though libgdx is a framework but its the most powerfull of them all and you can go very deep in the code (u might create some extraordinary events)...but for a beginner like me thats a tough one as i have no experience of game programming (also the kind of easy docu given at its site allures you to use it but after a while when you want to create something of your own you are puzzled)..
But the best performance is guranteed !!

Next comes the AndEngine ..excellent work doen by Nicolas..but alas the bug count is ever rising and there are not consistent results around the devices..its one of the major drawback..you can avoid bugs but when performance is hitted hard you have no option but to leave it !!

Cocos2d-x(this is what AndEngine without bugs and good-performance would be like in the future)..
but the only drawback with cocos is the programming on not-a-mac OS...you dont have the usual code completion and tiny-miny features which are programmers essentials these days..but for performance and bug-resistent coding we have a runner-up to libgdx !!

Comment: good comparison...!!
helpful !!

Comment: Good luck debugging cocos2d-x on Android. Also I'm not aware of "all those bugs" in AndEngine. Yes, there might be a bunch of github issues lined up, but I"m actively developing a game with it and haven't run into a single issue so far.

Comment: @NicolasGramlich sorry sire never thought i will hurt you but you might wanna have a look at this :
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/andengine-gles2-0-anchorcenter-book-t9411-60.html#p48473

Comment: also i have played some amazingly awesome games developed in cocos2dx...none i found for AndEngine !!
and also you are true genius (developing a game engine need to be one and to be in competition with all these around makes you more than just genius !!)..
i am a novice programmer so that was my xperience when i got introduced to all these engines !!

Comment: I didn't write the book, nor did I proof read it. It's solely the responsibility of the author to get the examples to run properly.

Awesome AndEngine games: Noogra Nuts, Bunny Shooter, Wheelz, Scramble With Friends, Hanging With Friends, FarmTower, 100 Doors, Xelorians, Dream Zoo, Dream Heights, Tracktor Digger, ZDefense, Greedy Spiders, Fireworks, ... those together have somewhere between 100M and 500M downloads. I haven't tracked any within the last year and I'm sure there is more out there.

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I would highly recommend LibGDX: native, good documentation, and large community/forum.